# Laravel 5.4 view <form> not POSTing all of form inputs to the respective controller

Tags: forms, laravel, post, controller, laravel-5.4

So I've hit a bit of a wall - I'm working on a Laravel 5.4 application and I want to POST form data from a view that I have created to its respective Controller. I've tested, and the data is getting sent to the right place, but out of all the different inputs (lesson_module_id, title, and description), only the "title" input is sending back the actual form input - all the others are "null" in the array that is passed back.

Maybe I've just spent too long looking at this and my brain is fried, but does anyone see what I'm missing? P.S., I've made sure the route is correct and the $request is actually going through!

Here's my HTML/Blade from the view:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('lessons.store') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('lesson_module_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
          <label for="lesson_module_id">Lesson Module</label>
          <select id="lesson_module_id" class="form-control" required>
            <option name="lesson_module_id" selected disabled>Please select a lesson module</option>
            @foreach ($lesson_modules as $lm)
              <option value="{{ $lm->id }}">{{ $lm->title }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>

          @if ($errors->has('lesson_module_id'))
            <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('lesson_module_id') }}</strong>
            </span>
          @endif

        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <label for="title">Title</label>

          <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" required autofocus>

          @if ($errors->has('title'))
            <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
            </span>
          @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <label for="description">Description</label>

          <textarea id="description" class="body-textarea medium-editor-textarea" rows="15" required></textarea>

          @if ($errors->has('description'))
            <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
            </span>
          @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Create Module">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And here's my controller store logic:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lesson = new Lesson;
    $lesson->lesson_module_id = $request->lesson_module_id;
    $lesson->title = $request->title;
    $lesson->description = $request->description;
    $lesson->save();

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot the name attributes in your htm for both of them.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! That's what I get for staring at that code for way too long.

Thanks for the quick help! You rock!